# can't get set interval to work

Tags: javascript, jquery

*EDIT: I inserted the missing code so you guys could see the boardGen() function. I reduced it to just 4 cases. However it still doesn't work. Can I not use the setInterval on the boardGen() function?*

I've written code that allows me to generate random letters on a 5X5 board. The code to generate the letters is really inefficient (a bunch of switch statements for each tile) but it works perfectly and generates a new set of letters every time I load the page.

I'm trying to get my random letter generator to switch every few seconds code to refresh. I researched and found that the setInterval function will allow me to do this. I've tried to follow the examples in the documentation but the code only executes once. The only effect the setInterval has is how long it takes to execute the first time. But after it executes, it stops. I know I left the boardGen function out. It's super long because I'm not that good. I just want to see if my setInterval code is correct. Can someone please help.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>LetterTouch</title>
</head>

  <link rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" href="gameboard.css">
  <!-- <link href="scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">

var nIntervId;

function changeLetters() {
    nIntervId = setInterval(boardGen, 1);
    }

function boardGen() {
// inefficient way of generating random letters for each tile//
    var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random()*4)+1);

    switch (randomNumber) {
        case 1:
            $("document").ready(function() {
                $("#squares").selectable();
                 $(".A1").replaceWith("<li>A</li>");
      });
       break;

        case 2:
        $("document").ready(function() {
                $("#squares").selectable();
                 $(".A1").replaceWith("<li>B</li>");
      });
      break;

        case 3:
        $("document").ready(function() {
                $("#squares").selectable();
                 $(".A1").replaceWith("<li>C</li>");
      });
      break;

        case 4:
        $("document").ready(function() {
                $("#squares").selectable();
                 $(".A1").replaceWith("<li>D</li>");
      });
      break;




      }

    }

 </script>

<body onload="changeLetters();">



<ol id="squares">
  <li class="A1"></li>
  <li class="A2"></li>
  <li class="A3"></li>
  <li class="A4"></li>
  <li class="A5"></li>
  <li class="B1"></li>
  <li class="B2"></li>
  <li class="B3"></li>
  <li class="B4"></li>
  <li class="B5"></li>
  <li class="C1"></li>
  <li class="C2"></li>
  <li class="C3"></li>
  <li class="C4"></li>
  <li class="C5"></li>
  <li class="D1"></li>
  <li class="D2"></li>
  <li class="D3"></li>
  <li class="D4"></li>
  <li class="D5"></li>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you do anything with the `nIntervId` variable?

Comment: Why obfuscating `boardGen()` something important to hide?

Comment: Ya you are correctly setting an interval here, your issue obviously comes from what you are doing inside `boardGen()` function. If it is an unefficient method, then firstly try to avoid to call it twice per second. BTW, any error in console?

Comment: Try `$(document).ready(changeLetters)`, instead of body onload.

Comment: As @A.Wolff says, the issue is likely to be in the boardGen function.

Comment: Have you got a clearInterval(nIntervId) inside your boardGen function?

Comment: Most likely `boardGen` has a local variable that you need to be a global (or closure) variable.

Comment: @Quentin it is set as global here and anyway works on first call. Did i misunderstand your comment?

Comment: Thanks everyone. Like A.Wolff said, it's must be the boardGen() function. I didn't post it because it's too long. It's a set of 26 switch statements for each tile in the 5X5 square. Inefficient, I know. I'll go back and try to write a better way of generating the board and then try the interval again. Since the problem is elsewhere, how to I close this question?

Comment: Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SH53B/ Works for me!

Comment: Holy cow, you weren't kidding, that's an inefficient way to generate a board. Check out the fiddle I posted. If this question weren't on hold, I'd paste it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks Joe Frambach, I read up on the .each() function you posted and that did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Your code works** (Firefox latest). It's something else.

(just changed interval to 5000 and added an alert for you) 
http://jsfiddle.net/6U7xM/1/

*FYI for readability of your code it's better to define `boardGen()` before using it in `changeLetters()`*

Comment: This is also not an answer.

Comment: "FYI best practice is to define boardGen() before changeLetters()" No sure why it would be a best practice here, functions are hoisted on same scope http://designpepper.com/blog/drips/variable-and-function-hoisting

Comment: Yes it is He asked (implicitly) "I just want to see if my setInterval code is correct."
Wolff you're right, it's for readability of code (define before use)

Comment: @JoeFrambach I'm agree on this point with user3041539, this answer the question as it has been asked

Comment: Yeah I see that. I guess it isn't *not* an answer.

Answer (score -3):

```
var nIntervId;

function changeLetters() {
    nIntervId = setInterval(boardGen, 500);
    function boardGen() {
        alert(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but what is the answer?

Comment: insert boardGen function into changeLetters function.